# Custom Delegate method is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have set up custom delegate as follows, but delegate method is not getting called. I wonder what I am missing in my following implementation.

**ComboSetViewController.h**

```
@protocol ComboSetViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)comboSelected;

@end

@interface ComboViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ComboSetViewControllerDelegate> comboSelectedDelegate;

@end
```

**ComboSetViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)doneBtnClicked
{
    selectedCombo.orderProductItemArray = comboOrderItemArray;
    [comboSelectedDelegate comboSelected];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**HomeViewController.h**

```
#import "ComboViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<ComboSetViewControllerDelegate>
```

**HomeViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ComboViewController *comboViewController = [[ComboViewController alloc] init];
    comboViewController.comboSelectedDelegate = self;
}

// is not getting called
-(void)comboSelected
{
    NSLog(@"Combo Selected");
}
```

**EDIT:** If I assign the `delegate` in the `prepareSegue`, then it works.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {    
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"isCombo"])
    {
        ComboViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        // Assign self as the delegate for the child view controller
        vc.comboSelectedDelegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are allocating a `ComboViewController` as a local variable in `viewDidLoad`. This object willl be released as soon as a `viewDidLoad` returns.  You need to assign your `HomeViewController` instance as a delegate to the instance of `ComboViewController` that is actually being presented.

Comment: @hotspring check if your delegate is nil?

Comment: @Paulw11, could you please illustrate your approach as an answer?

Comment: Why do you create and then never use an instance of `ComboViewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I see the issue, but how could I fix it?

Comment: You don't provide enough info for anyone to help. When and how should an instance of `ComboViewController` be created and presented?

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: OK, you solved your issue. You should delete your question.

Comment: That seems weird to have one VC be the delegate for another VC.  There really ought to be a control layer somewhere that manages the VCs and acts as their delegates.  That'll make refactoring easier in the future.

Comment: @bbum, I agree. What do you propose?

Comment: if you present or push navigation controller and called delegate method then it works. In your seague its pushing controller so that's why it is called in seague.

Comment: Could you please illustrate your approach?

Comment: @hotspring I'd generally delegate out from the view controllers to some kind of common control layer logic that would modify behavior accordingly.  I have found implementing the logic of behaviors with a bit of isolation from where it is used makes refactoring easier.  If you are moving the behavior from one transition to another, you only have to move the trigger.  And you don't have to duplicate if it crops up in more than one spot.

Comment: Is it ok to illustrate with an example?